# Why do i have to cast a Button?

Tags: java, android, button, view, casting

This must be a really dumb question because I cant find an answer online.... I know that casting is changing one datatype to another. How is this button ever changing it's data dype? `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.Bla.Bla)` Why cant we just write `Button button = New Button()` And then assign the xml to it another way? Please explain, I'm lost.

Comment: Casting does not mean changing a data type but threat an object as a specific type. Take a look at the Java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: So basically, we create a button and set it equal to a view object which is a parent class. According to the Java docs, child classes aren't neccesarily equal to their parents but parents can be equal to children. To avoid this innequality, we say that it is still a button with the = (Button)--- ? Why cant a child be equal to its parent? Is it because it's extra variables aren't in it's parent class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See In Android You can create the UI Elements in two ways:**

**1. create UI elements through layouts (.xml) files.**
    And to use them in java class map them to their corresponding class.
    And to do so we have to call method findViewById(int id); which returns the view of that perticuler element with given id.and thus we have to type cast it to respective component.
    And thus if you have created a element already in xml why will you create a different object again at java end. so just map the element created with xml file.

**2. crate UI elements through java end.**
    To use this feature use have to create the elements in java with new keywords ex. Button button = new Button(); and then set the all properties on that object.

**But But But,**
According to android philosophy you should create UI in xml, and write your core business logic in java end. And with this concept you can write neet and clean application code.
But it is only recommended not compulsory at all. now its up to you....
and i think at starting you feel it different but after some time you will start loving it...

Thats the beauty of android.

Thanks. i hope, i answered your question throughly.

Comment: SO is it just about connecting a parent type object?

Answer (score 6):

You *can* set a `Button` to a new button.

But `findViewById` returns a view. If you want to access any of its `Button`osity, you must cast, otherwise the reference isn't a button. There are times that may be okay, of course.

Comment: Exactly. You can declare UI elements in XML and use findViewById (and cast) OR instantiate layout elements at runtime.

Comment: @DaveNewton The reference _is_ a button, it's just that the compiler cannot be sure of that during compile time, therefore it asks you for a cast to make your intention explicit. Casting doesn't make a button out of something else. If it wasn't a button, the code would just fail.

Comment: @AlaksiejN. The *reference* isn't a button, that which it *references* is a button. But I think we're discussing English semantics rather than Java.

Answer (score 2):

Also, remember that `Button` is a subclass of `View`. The `findViewById()` method returns a generic `View` (any `View` or subclass of `View` that you put in a layout file). The cast to `Button` is saying "It's okay - I know this is a Button, not just a regular View," which allows you to access properties and methods of the `Button` that aren't available in the `View` superclass.

Comment: So a child class cant be defined as a parent class because it encapsulates more methods and variables than the parent class has, right? The view button xml is already defined as a View object and not a sublcass button. So we have a problem when adding the two. So we create  a cast that is a button/alreadyDefinedViewParent right?

Answer (score 2):

`final Button callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callButton);`

I believe that when finding an XML view using `findViewbyId()`, it returns the view in the UI, but the returned view must be *cast* in order to be used as a button within the Java code, and have access to the *button methods*.

There are ways to create a button in the Java code without specifying it in the XML, but this practice differentiates the UI from the logic.

Plus, declaring UI elements in the XML is better because it is makes the process changing entire layouts easy through usage of of `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to create `View` component in android including `Button`

1- Define it in a `layout` XML file and access it using `(Button) findViewById(R.id.button)`

2- Create it dynamically in the code e.g. `Button button = new Button();`

both has their own advantages and disadvantages, for example, defining the `UI` in `layout` xml makes your `Activity` concise and and give you more flexibility by separating the `UI` from the actual code

Dynamic `UI` creation is useful in many applications that needs to create `Views` **on-the-fly**